# Difference Between Dinner and Supper

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between dinner and supper?
I understand both as the same meal.

In *The Hound of the Baskervilles*, there is this sentence:

> And now, if we are too late for dinner, I think that we are both ready for our suppers.
> <sub>Source: [*The Hound of the Baskervilles*](http://books.google.com/books?id=5l8rUHN9STcC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=%22And+now,+if+we+are+too+late+for+dinner,+I+think+that+we+are+both+ready+for+our+suppers.%22&source=bl&ots=xxzIE82dNM&sig=dLMFhvB65GvUF2REKSmDcYNzOx8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HwwSVIbuH8W0yASbzoCQDQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22And%20now%2C%20if%20we%20are%20too%20late%20for%20dinner%2C%20I%20think%20that%20we%20are%20both%20ready%20for%20our%20suppers.%22&f=false)</sub>

From this sentence, it seems like you're supposed to have dinner, and then have supper?
I am really confused.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24593/dinner-is-lunch/24619, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings

Comment: Note the comments that "supper" is not something you will generally hear in America.  Since it is so infrequently used, those infrequent usages are often referencing ["The Last Supper"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(disambiguation)).  "Dinner" is used almost exclusively in American English at this time.  When I was a kid I occasionally remember "supper" was used sometimes by the older people in the Southern US... but I am currently living in the Southern US and haven't heard it spoken in years.

Comment: @HostileFork My grandmother is from NE USA and she would use dinner for lunch and supper for the meal after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dinner** is usually taken in the evenings or noon (according to some cultures) is the main meal of the day. However **supper** is a light meal that is taken in the evenings (for example, before bed-time)
.